# Bash script help | mongoDB

Tags: bash, mongodb

I am writing a bash script which uses mongoimport utility to add data to the database.

The following command runs successfully:

```
$ mongoimport -h localhost:27017 -d test -c ecg --fieldFile data/ecg_fields --type csv --file data/temp_ecg_data
```

Next, I put it in a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1
DATABASE=$2
COLLECTION=$3
FIELDFILE=$4
FIELDTYPE=$5
FILE=$6

mongoimport -h $HOST -d $DATABASE -c $COLLECTION --fieldFile $FIELDFILE --type $FILETYPE --file $FILE
```

Now, I get an error. Here is the output:

```
connected to: localhost:27017
Sat Dec 08 15:49:44 ERROR: don't know what type [--file] is
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You've mistakenly referred to FILETYPE not FIELDTYPE. Tweaked a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=$1
DATABASE=$2
COLLECTION=$3
FIELDFILE=$4
FIELDTYPE=$5
FILE=$6

if [[ -z "$6" ]] ; then
   echo "Usage: ..." 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

mongoimport -h "$HOST" -d "$DATABASE" -c "$COLLECTION" --fieldFile "$FIELDFILE" --type "$FIELDTYPE" --file "$FILE"
```

Comment: You should explain what you the condition does, too.